# What is autoIndex as it relates to a web server?

Tags: node.js, web, httpserver

What does **autoIndex** mean as it relates to a web server? I'm interested to know specifically in the context of this Node.js app, [http-server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server). I've seen the term used in a number of other questions on stackoverflow without a definition.

In the mentioned app's [execution options](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server#available-options), it is listed as "Display autoIndex", discrete from another option "Show directory listings". I understand the latter (Show directory listings) to mean that the app will, in the event of a user's navigating to a directory missing a file with the default extension, construct a web page displaying a list of links to the files and subfolders within that directory. However, I do not understand what **autoIndex** means, as I cannot find an authoritative definition of it online. Can anyone explain it to me, hopefully linking to some documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`autoIndex = true;` means to respond with `/path/index.html` when `/path/` is requested. It's a part of [ecstatic](https://github.com/jesusabdullah/node-ecstatic) package api.